# Try/catch statement jumps to end of program

Tags: java

I have a try/catch statment in main, and looking in the debugger, i can see that it declairs my varables at the start, then goes to the try/catch statement, and then when it gets to catch, it terminates.

```
@SuppressWarnings("null")
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Robot robot = null;
    try {
        robot = new Robot();
    } catch (AWTException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
```

I'm a bit of a noob to java btw.
An exeption was never thrown, once ran it outputs terminated Main (1) [Java Application] C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_144\bin\javaw.exe

Comment: Did it print any error message out when it terminated?
It might be a RuntimeException?

Comment: Looks like you triggered a different exception.

Comment: What were you expecting it to do?

Comment: You're missing some stuff at the end there...

Comment: "AWTException - if the platform configuration does not allow low-level input control. This exception is always thrown when GraphicsEnvironment.isHeadless() returns true"

Comment: Once I ran it, it just said "terminated".

Comment: As opposed to...?

Comment: Like other people have said, you probably need to give more details. Does it complete the construction of the Robot object? Was any exception even thrown or did the program just end normally? What makes you think something is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Robot robot = null;
    try {
        robot = new Robot();
    } catch (AWTException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Throwable th) {
        th.printStackTrace();
    } 
}
```

The problem is almost certainly that some exception other than AWTException is being thrown. (My money, since you're a self-described noob, is on NullPointerException.)  Anyway, nothing will throw past this:  Not all things that can be thrown are children of Exception, but they are all children of Throwable.